# Google Play developer application name update

Tags: android, google-play-services

I changed my Android app name in Google Play developer and in Android Studio too.
But when I try to find my app using new name no success, I only can find it using previous name.

Why can its happened? How can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

it usually takes 24 hours for changes to take place, wait and it'll be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to change the label in the manifest too?

Both your application and activity fields should contain:

```
android:label="Name You Want Here"
```

Answer (score 0):

It normally takes a few hours untill changes get upadted in the play store.